# Counterfactuals for Variables with Negative Values

Tags: regression, prediction, causality

Lets imagine I have estimated the following simple linear regression model:
$y_{i} = 10 + 0.5x_{i} + \varepsilon_{i} $, and want to work out the counter-factual, or what would $ y_{i}$ be in the absence of $ x_{i}$.

The most simple example of this is a simple treatment control case. So $x_{i} = T_{i}$ and $T \in \{0,1\}$. In this case there are two possible counter-factual outcomes:

1: Get the treatment, so $ T=1$ and the counter-factual is $y_{i}-0.5T_{i}=y_{i}-0.5$,

2: Don't, so $ T=0$ and the counter-factual is simply $y_{i}-0.5T_{i}=y_{i}$.

This is easy enough to understand. However, I am having a lot of trouble with calculating such counter-factuals in the case where $ x_{i}$ takes negative values. In my case, I have a continuous regressor $ x_{i}$, that has values roughly ranging from $-8$ to $+ 1$.

To see my issue, lets assume the same regression model as in the above, and try to work out the counter-factual values of $ y_{i}$ for two potential values of $ x_{i} \in \{-2, -1\}$.

For $x_{1}=-2$, the lower value, the predicted impact of this on the outcome is: $0.5(-2)=-1$.

For $x_{2}=-1$, the greater value, the predicted impact of this on the outcome is: $0.5(-1)=-0.5$.

Obviously, the lower value of $x$ has less of an impact on the outcome as $-1<-0.5$.

However, this is the point where my brain goes dead. How do you translate this into a counter-factual outcome? From before, we had a formula: $y_{i}-0.5x_{i}$. Although, in this case using this formula predicts the opposite.

$y_{1}-0.5(-1)=y_{1}+0.5$

$y_{2}-0.5(-2)=y_{2}+1$

So in the absence of $x_{i}$ both values of $y$ would be, greater even though the estimated coefficient is positive. I am really struggling with this. Is there some kind of transformation I can do that allows the counter-factual values of the higher values of $x_{i}$ to shrink while the lower values of $x_{i} $ shrink less (or not at all) as in the $x_{i}=T_{i}\in\{0,1\}$ case?

To further elaborate, I want to be able to predict a lot of counter-factual values for a continuous treatment effect, but I want to be able to use these counter-factual values to work out how much of the variation in $y$ is caused by $x$. Let us imagine we are talking about the outcome being economic growth. We want to find out how much good political institutions ($x$) explain of economic growth ($y$). What I would like to do is see what these growth rates were like if institutions did not matter.

For example, imagine we have estimated the regression model given in the above for 2 countries: A and B. In A, there are good institutions so $x_{A}=4$, and B is bad so $x_{B}=1$. Now let us say that economic growth in A is $y_{A}=4$ and $y_{B}=2$. So in this case, the counter-factuals (what growth would be if $x$ didn't matter) would be $4-0.5(4)=2$ and $2-0.5(1)=1.5$ for A and B respectively. In the counter-factual scenario the sum of growth rates is 3.5, as opposed to the observed 6. This means that in the absence of institutions we would have had ($\frac{3.5}{6} \approx 58\%$) of the the growth. So institutions explain $42\%$ of the growth difference between these two countries. With negative values of $x$ I am not sure how to go about performing such a calculation.

Comment: Is your confusion alleviated if you recognize that, despite -1 being *smaller* than -0.5, it is still *more* change than -0.5?

Comment: In other words, you say "Obviously, the lower value of x has less of an impact on the outcome as −1<−0.5." But that's not so obvious to me. -1 is more extreme than -.5. When you're talking about impact, you should probably be thinking in terms of *absolute* change.

Comment: But how does this translate into the calculation of the counter-factual value? For example, let us imagine that $ y_{1} = 10$ so the counter-factual for $ y_{1}$ is $10.5$. However, we know that the effect is positive. How in the absence of $x_{i}$ can the outcome be greater when the coefficient is positive?

Comment: if $x_i$ is negative, then removing $\beta x_i$ where $\beta$ is positive will have a positive impact on the whole net of all else. That's just a fact.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the response. I think I need to elaborate my original post.

Comment: I suspect that the problem you're having here may be due to more murky definition of "in the absence of X" when X is polytomous/continuous. When X is binary, it makes more sense - in the absence of treatment, the individual does not get treated. Your method for calculating counterfactuals is a new one to me; could you point me to a paper/reference? Regardless, the regression estimation presumably uses all the values of your X variable available and so there shouldn't be a difference between the calculation for a binary vs continuous variable.